# How to link navigation/buttons to the whole site using one file?

Tags: php, html

Is there a quicker way to make the navigation bar/buttons go onto all my pages of my site instead of going into each .php file and copying and pasting it. How would I link up the class="button" to another file so that it changes the whole navigation on my site?

Comment: Uhh... use an include?

Comment: Put the menu in a different .php file and then include it from the other pages.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 1):

Just use an [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement.

`include 'nav.php';`

on each page.

Nav.php could then contain nothing more than just the navigation.

Comment: So right now my html looks a bit like this : <li><a href="terms.php<?php echo $referral_string?>" class="button">terms</a></li> <style> "my code for my button" </style>. So my question is where would I put this so that each page knows to link up to this nav.php?

Comment: the style would go in your `<head>` tag. The `li` would go inside a `ul` inside the nav.php.

Answer (score 0):

First Separate  your php file as header.php for header menu and footer.php for footer menu.
And then include the file in pages .

[See this example for reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)